# When you suggest an edit to a tag wiki the suggested edits counter is increased

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, top-bar

When you (that is, *you* and not somebody else) suggest an edit to a tag wiki the counter on the suggested edits tab on the review page is increased by one. This seems to be wrong if the function of the counter is to inform of the number of edits you *can* act on. When you suggested an edit of a tag wiki then you cannot, and rightly so, review that very edit (when you enter the suggested edits page your suggested edit does not appear there).

Comment: That number is very heavily cached. The likelihood they'll "fix" this is incredibly low.